# How to get data from table by like query

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have some problem in query I have two tables

1. `appcp_sound_attributes`
2. `appcp_vocalize`

`appcp_sound_attributes` contain field name "`name`" and `appcp_vocalize` contain field "`attributes`"

I want to get data from "`appcp_vocalize`" using like query Eg `appcp_vocalize.attributes like '%' + appcp_sound_attributes.name + '%'`

My query is  :

```
   SELECT * 
FROM appcp_vocalize 
JOIN appcp_sound_attributes
    ON appcp_vocalize.attributes LIKE '%appcp_sound_attributes.name%'
```

Please give the best solution of this query

Comment: Why don't you add 2 primary auto incrementing columns for each table?

Comment: @Mihai appcp_vocalize.attributes  is json value I want to find json data by like clause according to 'appcp_sound_attributes.name'

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?  Those are separate databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  It will give you any matching records where the appcp_vocalize.attributes field contains the appcp_sound_attributes.name field.

```
SELECT * 

FROM   appcp_vocalize 

       JOIN appcp_sound_attributes
       ON INSTR(appcp_vocalize.attributes, appcp_sound_attributes.name) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for reply its working , Please give me suggestion how can I create separate result for both  its give me the combined result of both tables

Comment: I don't understand.  What do you want to see?  Both of these tables have differing fields correct?

Comment: No some field are same

Comment: If you post what you would like your desired output to be, perhaps I could help.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for this `CONCAT('%',appcp_vocalize.attributes,'%')`